# Is there a solution for problem for not showing project properties in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, properties, mfc, project, visual-studio-2022

I changed the language from Korean to English in Visual Studio 2022, but when I open the properties window of the project, only the configuration properties window and the code analysis window appear. How can I solve this?
Korean

[image: 1]

English

[image: 2]

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: yes. but it didn't worked

Comment: In the Visual Studio Installer the Language Packs are all separate options. Perhaps you don't have the English pack installed?

Comment: No I already installed english pack

Comment: It's Solved. the problem was that I used VS2022, but project is VS2010 version. so I need to install VS2010 Language Pack(English).

Comment: @tyjjh you can write up an answer post and mark it as accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I used VS2022, but project is VS2010 version. so I need to install VS2010 Language Pack(English).